# How can I run a cli app in a pod inside a Kubernetes cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, command-line-interface

I have a cli app written in NodeJS [not by me].

I want to deploy this on a k8s cluster like I have done many times with web servers.

I have not deployed something like this before, so I am in a kind of a loss.

I have worked with dockerized cli apps [like Terraform] before, and i know how to use them in a CICD.

But how should I deploy them in a pod so they are always available for usage from another app in the cluster?

Or is there a completely different approach that I need to consider?

#EDIT#

I am using this in the end of my Dockerfile ..

```
# the main executable
ENTRYPOINT ["sleep", "infinity"]
# a default command
CMD ["mycli help"]
```

That way the pod does not restart and the cli inside is waiting for commands like `mycli do this`

Is it a `hacky` way that is frowned upon or a legit solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your edit is one solution, another one if you do not want or cannot change the Docker image is to [Define a Command for a Container](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-command-argument-container/) to loop infinitely, this would achieve the same as the Dockerfile ENTRYPOINT but without having to rebuild the image.

Here's an example of such implementation:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: command-demo
  labels:
    purpose: demonstrate-command
spec:
  containers:
  - name: command-demo-container
    image: debian
    command: ["/bin/sh", "-ec", "while :; do echo '.'; sleep 5 ; done"]
  restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

As for your question about if this is a legit solution, this is hard to answer; I would say it depends on what your application is designed to do. Kubernetes Pods are designed to be ephemeral, so a good solution would be one that is running until the job is completed; for a web server, for example, the job is never completed because it should be constantly listening to requests.

Comment: Thank you Gabriel, that is helpful. Actually, as I understand, the devs just want a cli inside a pod that can is always there up and running, and can execute commands. Pretty much like a webserver.  
EDIT: I discussed the way pods are working and they added command line args in order for the process to stay alive.

Answer (score 0):

If your pods are in the same cluster they are already available to other pods through Core-DNS. An internal DNS service which allows you to access them by their internal DNS name. Something like `my-cli-app.my-namespace.svc.cluster`. [DNS for service and pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/)

You would then create a deployment file with all your apps. Note this doesn't need ports to  work and also doesn't include communication through the internet.

```
#deployment.yaml

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.14.2
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

Comment: I am describing the use of a cli app like this https://hub.docker.com/r/hashicorp/terraform/dockerfile . nginx is a common webserver that I know how to deploy and the pod stays up cause nginx is always running.